# Play alarm on url access

Tags: linux, audio, apache-http-server, nginx

I wanted to do a simple webserver which if I or someone accesses the url i.e https://example.com/playalarm, it would play a specified audio file on attached speakers on my box.

Something using a terminal player ffplay, mplayer, vlc, etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: Play on what system? The client or the server?

Comment: @Appleoddity on the server.

Comment: Read the apache documentation, find out how to execute a script on access to an URL. First write a script that appends a line to a file, so you can test it. Then figure out how to play sound in an environment without an X (so no `vlc`...), and convince Pulseaudio to accept connections from a "non-desktop" user that isn't even logged in ... or disable Pulseaudio and use ALSA. Oh, and don't give me the URL, or I'd be tempted to write a script to play your alarm 24/7...

Answer (score 0):

**Overview**

This could be accomplished with a command line script or an executable file ran via [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) (or perhaps [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI)). How you would go about implementing your desired behavior specifically would depend on the server software and the programming or scripting language you chose to implement it in.

**CGI vs. FastCGI**

CGI is the older protocol and is likely easier to implement overall. However, it doesn't scale well with a large amount of requests and so FastCGI was developed. Either protocol could be used in your case, but this decision will likely be influenced primarily by the web server you run. Apache has support for both CGI and FastCGI, while Nginx supports only FastCGI.

CGI and FastCGI scripts are typically implemented in C/C++ (as executable programs) or popular scripting languages such as Python, Perl and Ruby (as scripts). Whatever language you choose, all the languages listed above should be supported by CGI (at minimum). The scripting languages mentioned should be installed on your system prior to their use in any CGI scripts.

---

*Please note I am specifically ignoring WSGI/uWSGI or other language-specific protocols in this answer.*

---

**Example Python CGI Script**

To keep things relatively simply, the following script was written with Python and called with Apache using basic CGI. This script assumes that the URL you are using is calling this script directly (ex. https://example.com/playalarm is referring to https://example.com/playalarm.py).

*ex. playalarm.py*

```
#!/path/to/python3

# A CGI script in Python to play a sound with ffplay when a URL is accessed.
# This script assumes Python 3.5 or higher is being used and that the
# script itself resides in a directory has been properly configured
# to allow CGI script execution.

# --- Play Sound ---

# Our script commands having nothing to do with our HTML document (below).
# We use ffplay to play our audio file. Note that we likely need to use
# "-nodisp -autoexit" to keep the script from "hanging" indefinitely.
# Alternately, you can try 'ffplay -nodisp -autoexit sound.mp3 >/dev/null 2>&1' (as needed).

# The line below assumes beep.mp3 resides in our script directory.
# You can specify a full path to the audio clip as necessary.

import os
import subprocess

subprocess.run ('ffplay -nodisp -autoexit beep.mp3')


# --- HTML Document ---

# Since this is a standard CGI script, we are expected to return
# e.g. a standard HTML document. In fact, we need to return e.g. a
# document to avoid an internal server error.

# The following lines (or something very similar) are required,
# regardless of CGI script type.

# print ("Content-type: text/plain")
print ("Content-type: text/html")
print ("")

# We can leave the script here. A blank page will be displayed
# but the script should execute successfully.

# However, we have decided to return an HTML 5 document that
# instantly redirects to another page (e.g. example.com).
# But this is just an example.

print ("<!doctype html>")
print ("<html>")
print ("")
print ("<head>")
print ('    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com">')
print ("</head>")
print ("")
print ("<body>")
print ("</body>")
print ("")
print ("</html>")
```

**Caveats**

As alluded to in the comments, there may be any number of things you need to work out in order to allow this script (or whatever you end up using) to run on your target system. This question is not intended to address server environment, web server configuration, permissions, whether a script can be executed, security concerns, more advanced script or program implentations, etc. Simply be aware that you may have additional work or issues ahead of you.